# If a police officer has taken the keys of my car away from me, who are the police allowed to return them to?

Tags: criminal-law

I was accused of stealing from a store from a worker so she tried to stop me from driving away. I was later arrested by the police because she claimed that I was attempting to harm her with my car. The keys to my car were taken and I wasn’t allowed to take any of my belongings out of the car such as my phone or wallet. When they arrived they hand cuffed me and didn’t listen to anything I said, I was taken to the police station where I was finally listened to. They finally heard my side of the story and found out I was right. I asked for the keys of my car back and they told me that they gave them to the passenger in my car at the time of the incident. The person that was in my car has now stolen my car and everything in it. All they said was that they’re sorry and that I should report it.

Comment: This question needs a country tag. Where did this happen? (and are you sure they were the real police? Was the police station the police station you recognize, or some small office somewhere?)

Comment: I can't believe they gave the keys to the passenger - not without you giving them permission to drive the car, and them being **insured** to drive it too. This desperately needs a country tag. (in the UK the police would need to be happy those two conditions exist, or they would confiscate the keys and have it towed)